# What building is this?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture

[image: screenshot]

This image is a screenshot from a video, and in the video the image is named "UK".

What building is this?

Comment: Can you give us that context? A link to the video, etc?

Comment: @Flimzy: the video is a Photoshop tutorial, and the presenter named the image layer "UK"

Comment: @dmr, Always [edit] clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them buried in comments where people won't see them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it is a part of the [Brighton royal pavilion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Pavilion) in Brighton, England.

[image]

Comment: I had a walkthrough on Google maps just to see the size of this.

Comment: Definitely, recognised it immediately from the OP's image, great shot you've found of it!

Comment: It doesn't look the same to me. Similar but not the same. Compare the details. Maybe it's a much larger structure than is shown here and the questioner's view is somewhere else.

Comment: I was skeptical, because there are differences between what is shown here and what the OP posted. But [this picture shows the dome in the OP](http://vikingsinspace.wordpress.com/page/18/).

Comment: Thanks @DJClayworth.  I knew that the picture I posted wasn't the same dome, but I thought it was a better shot of the building as a whole.

Comment: It is one of the towers at the back http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/00/1d/2c/7a/royal-pavilion.jpg

Comment: I live in Brighton. I'm pretty sure that's the royal pavilion. I think that's one of the smaller domes by the entrance. The pavilion is the Prince Regent's pleasure palace. It's worth a visit it you're in the area and you like lots of gold, indian themed statuary and chandeliers the size of small cars.